# Edit corresponding cell values of a jqgrid row when click on another cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I had displayed the data in jqgrid by formatting the values as below

### GroupName GroupDesc Action

### [Hari](http://example.com/) desc1 [Edit](http://example.com/)

Here **Groupname** and **Edit** values will have hyperlinks. 
When I click on the Edit hyperlink the other two cells in a row has to be edited.
There is a option for inline edit in jqgrid but the client requirement is to edit the row when click on the action value. I tried to with the editrow option of jqgrid but not succeeded.
could anyone help in how to achieve this edit option without selecting the checkbox of the row.

Comment: Sorry, If my question is not understanding, Please let me know if anything i need to add in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use a link, try with a `onCellSelect` event.

$("#gridid").jqGrid({

```
onCellSelect: function(rowid, iCol, cellcontent){ 

    if(cellcontent=="EDIT"){      

        $("#gridid").jqGrid('editRow',rowid);

    } 

},
```

});